# How to create png mask from GeoJSON

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, geojson

I have 650 png images and for each of them a geogson mask. How I can combine them to input into Unet (capillaries in eye segmentation problem)?
I've found https://products.aspose.app/gis/viewer/geojson-to-png, but 650 photos..
Second problem - I'm not sure in mask rotation - mask can be flipped. There are two random examples:
[eye](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2779u.png),  [mask created by the link above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hJEc.png),
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qlza.jpg), [second mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDYFA.png) (as you can see, second example is rotated)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think you'd be more likely to get an answer if you shared a GeoJSON mask and its corresponding image and provided the expected output... along with your latest/greatest attempt at coding it.

Comment: Thanks to you, but I downloaded QuPath. After creating two scripts this program done my all